# Delete Common Child Nodes of db-B and db-A

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, child-nodes

I am using Firebase for my android studio project and am facing a problem.

Say I have two databases like this:

[image]

and

[image]

I want to search the userids that are common in A and B (i.e. here ABC and DEF) and delete them from both the database A and B.

How to do that? Thanks in advance.

P.S- I am giving a simpler view of the databases with just userid as child.

Comment: Sounds like a fairly straightforward coding exercise: load the users from both. loop through one list, check if the user exists in the other. if so, delete from both. Which step has you stuck?

Comment: can you please give the code of the loop? I think it is not usual for loop with int or string variable

Comment: If you search for [comparing two lists](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+android+compare+two+lists), you're bound to find some relevant code to start with.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: Yes. I just solved it @AlexMamo . It was really cool for me to figure out the code. Thank you all.